# Could I send TWO parameters over $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an app with AngularJS, and the question is:
I have links as part of a list of contacts that belong to a company, built with ng-repeat. After clicking it I should go to the details page of that (changing state).

But since I have already the organization’s name and I would like to avoid a second call to the API to get a name of the company I already have. Could I send TWO parameters over $stateParams like:

```
<a ui-sref=”contact/({id: contact.id})&((id: organization.id)}”>{{contact.name}}</a>
```

How would it look like in the app.js file?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId&:organizationId",
        templateUrl: 'views.contactDetail.html',
        controller: contactsController,
        params: {
                contactId: null,
        organizationId
            },
    })
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not the syntax.  It's JS object notation.  And you can't name both things Id.

Comment: Is `url: "/contacts/:organizationId/:contactId"` something you considered?

Comment: you want to both parameter optional or mandatory?

Comment: @taguenizy, that url would be ok, but how would be the controller?

Comment: @RafaelMunoz it would be `$stateParams.organizationId` and `$stateParams.contactId`

Answer (score 2):

```
<a ui-sref=”contacts({contactId:obj.contactId,organizationId:obj.organizationId})”>{{contact.name}}</a>

$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId/:organizationId",
        templateUrl: 'views.contactDetail.html',
        controller: contactsController,

    })
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, I implemented this solution but I have got an empty url like: http://localhost:50895/contacts//. What does it means the "OBJ" in the Url?

Comment: obj means contact.id for obj.contactId and organization.id for obj.organizationId try this